# Azure VM fails to register in the DNS server external to Azure

Tags: azure

We are trying to register the Azure VM to our own DNS Server but not able to do so.

We have already setup the VPC, Virtual Network and Gateway to connect to our DNS server.

we have also specified our DNS server within the Virtual network.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you're asking, are you trying to do a DNS update? what are the details of the DNS server? (software / OS etc) have you checked logging to see if you are receiving queries? Help us to understand what your problem is, so we can take a reasonable stab at answering it

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're looking to register your VMs internal IPs in your DNS server.  Is that correct?

If so, Windows clients do this automatically when domain joined and will send an unsecured Dynamic DNS update when not domain joined but you need to create a DNS zone for the records and allow unsecured updates, which is not the default.  Linux clients need a script added to the DHCP client to send the dynamic DNS updates.   I'm in the process of creating a page on Azure.com for this and can share the commands in the meantime if you're using that setup.

Gareth
(Azure DNS)